# AngularJS http status 0 and redirection

Tags: angularjs, coldfusion, angularjs-http

I have an application with Angularjs and Coldfusion.
I have a form with some http queries for populating drop-down list.
When the session server is out, I retrieve the status from the server, I display a dialog box (thanks to ngDialog) and I reload the page.(status 0 sent by the server because the server tries to reload an external authentication system before going on the main page of the application - not in the scope of this topic).

Here **my code**:

```
app.controller('ctrlAddContacts', function ($scope, $route, ContactService, ngDialog, $timeout){

    ContactService.getCountry().success(function(countries){
        $scope.countries = countries;       
    }); 

    ContactService.loadCategory('undefined',0).success(function(categories, status, header, config){
        $scope.categories = categories;
        console.log("status:" + status);        
    })
    .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
        console.log("sessionExpired: " + sessionExpired);
        console.log("ERROR ");
        console.log("data: " + data);
        console.log("status:" + status);
        console.log("header: " + header);
        console.log("config: " + config);
               if (status==0) {
                    alert("Your session expired - The page needs to be reloaded.\nPlease note that data enter in the form will be lost");        

                    // NGDIALOG BOX

                        var dialog = ngDialog.open({
                            template: '<p>Your session expired - The page needs to be reloaded.<br />Please note that data enter in the form will be lost</p>',
                            plain: true,
                            closeByDocument: false,
                            closeByEscape: false
                        });
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            dialog.close();
                            window.location = "http://myapp/index.cfm?#/add-contacts";      
                        }, 4000);


                }                   
    }).finally(function() {
      console.log("finally finished repos");
    }); 

});
```

It's working but I have to do that for each ajax HTTP request.

Here I have to do the same for:

```
   ContactService.getCountry().success(function(countries){
        $scope.countries = countries;      
    });
```

Thus I wouldd like to simplify the code in order to avoid to repeat the line, could you tell me please if I can do that and how (directive or factory for instance)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `service` to handle all `$http` in your controllers, in this sample i try to connect `controller` and `service` by using `$q` to pass response from service result is dialog will handle in the service also you can get the response in your controller.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function ($scope, service) {
    service.get('getCountry').then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    })
})

app.service("service", function ($http, $q, ContactService, ngDialog, $timeout) {
    this.get = function (api) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        //we used angular 1.6 => use then instead success
        ContactService[api]().then(function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        }, function (error) {
            if (error.status == 0) {
                alert("Your session expired - The page needs to be reloaded.\nPlease note that data enter in the form will be lost");
                var dialog = ngDialog.open({
                    template: '<p>Your session expired - The page needs to be reloaded.<br />Please note that data enter in the form will be lost</p>',
                    plain: true,
                    closeByDocument: false,
                    closeByEscape: false
                });
                $timeout(function () {
                    dialog.close();
                    window.location = "http://myapp/index.cfm?#/add-contacts";
                }, 4000);
            } else {
                alert("status is " + error.status);
            }
        })

        return deferred.promise;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use interceptors for this,

```
.factory('myInterceptor', ['$q', '$location', '$injector', function ($q, $location, $injector) {
    return {
        response: function (response) {
            if (response.status === 0) {
                console.log('http 0 response')
            }
            return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function (rejection) {
            return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
    }
}])
.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
}]);
```

Also interceptors can be used for global error handling, authentication, or any kind of synchronous or asynchronous pre-processing of request or postprocessing of responses.